# UIWebView Catch event when WebView cant find Address

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Just wondering if there is an event on a UIWebView that I can catch when the web address it is viewing cannot be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the load of a webpage fails, UIWebView will call the `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` method on its delegate.

Comment: when I enter in a crap link like "sadkfhd" that event doesnt seem to fire??

Comment: When I enter a crap link like that, it logs an error "Unknown scheme, doing nothing" after calling `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:`. OTOH, if I enter a crap link like "`http://sadkfhd`" that at least has a proper scheme, `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` is called as expected.